# How to error out main script, after few iterations

Tags: shell-script, scripting, error-handling

I'm trying to build logic for the pseudo-code below:

```
if 'main' job fails
 sleep 60
  re-trigger main job for 3 times.
after re-triggering for 3 times if it still fails , 
then kill the main job .




ksh 123.ksh ##main command
if [[ $?!=0 ]]
then
sleep 30
    ksh 123.ksh
if [[ $?!=0 ]]
then
sleep 30
    ksh 123.ksh

fi
fi
```

Here i can add one more $? check and then do a sleep 30 , like this i can continue for 3 or 4 times.
but im looking for in more generic way.

I cannot come up with a logic to re-trigger 3 times and fail out.

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far? It's often easier for us to build on what you already understand than start from nothing

Comment: ksh 123.ksh ##main command
if [[ $?!=0 ]]
then
sleep 30
    ksh 123.ksh
if [[ $?!=0 ]]
then
sleep 30
    ksh 123.ksh

fi
fi

Here i can add one more $? check and then do a sleep 30 , like this i can continue for 3 or 4 times. 
but im looking for in more generic way.

Comment: Why do you need to kill the job if it fails in the end? How do you detect a failing job? Please update the text and code in the question.

Comment: there are few DB related issues which is causing the failure coz of number of threads at DB end. Mostly the job complets after 2 -3 re-runs coz all those occupied threads will be free-ed up. im trying to automate this by making it sleep and then re-run after nseconds

Comment: @buchiki Consider putting your clarification into the actual question. Maybe also mention what database engine you're dealing with just in case someone familiar with it has an even better solution for you that is not based on a shell script hack like this.

Comment: @kusalananda , im using oracle and its shared one, we have few high demanding applicatons/jobs which spawn multiple threads. tired of re-positioning jobs to look for threads. so instead im trying to run the job untill it finds available threads.

Comment: @buchiki Again, I'm asking you to please update the text of your question to include any clarification there.

Comment: i think i explained my question well. im new to scripting and im not sure what else is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
#! /bin/sh -
remaining_attempts=3; until main-job; do
  if [ "$(( remaining_attempts -= 1 ))" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo>&2 "Giving up"
    exit 1
  fi
  sleep 60
done
```